# change img scr base on click icon

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created a join event table with each rows are populated by events so when I ever I click join the icon will change. My problem is when ever I click an event the icon it changes but does not correspond to a correct rows that I click only the first row icon will change even if I click the middle row.

```
<td>
 <a href="#" class="join_now" id="<?php echo $row['event_id'];?>">

    <?php $join=$ db->verify_already_join($official_id, $id); if ($join == 0) { echo "

    <img src='images/join.png' id='join' width='30' height='30' />"; } else { echo "

    <img src='icon/votenow.png' id='join' width='30' height='30' />"; } ?>

 </a>
<td>
```

My Ajax JQUERY

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var name = <? php echo json_encode($name); ?> ;
        var off_id = <? php echo json_encode($official_id); ?> ;
        $(".join_now").live("click", function () {
            var id_value = $(this).attr("id");
            var newSrc = 'icon/votenow.png';
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "join.now.php",
                data: "id=" + id_value + "&name=" + name + "&official=" + off_id,
                success: function (html) {
                    if (html == '0') {
                        $(".err_msg").html("<strong><font color='red'>You have Successfully Join this Event!</font></strong>");
                        $('#join').attr('src', newSrc);
                    }
                    if (html == '1') {

                        $(".err_msg").html("<strong><font color='red'>You Already Join this Event!</font></strong>");
                    }
                },
                beforeSend: function () {
                    $(".err_msg").html("<strong>Loading...</strong>")
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
           $('#join').attr('src', newSrc);
```

that line will always change the image of the first element that has an id of join. You code is wrong because in your table there will be multiple elements with an id of join.. that is wrong. In your DOM, there should not be 2 elements with the same id.

Change your img code to be

```
<td>
 <a href="#" class="join_now" id="<?php echo $row['event_id'];?>">

    <?php $join=$ db->verify_already_join($official_id, $id); if ($join == 0) { echo "

    <img src='images/join.png' class='join' width='30' height='30' />"; } else { echo "

    <img src='icon/votenow.png' class='join' width='30' height='30' />"; } ?>

 </a>
<td>
```

Then the code to change the image src instead it should be

```
           $('#'+id_value + ' .join').attr('src', newSrc);
```

and you have your self a properly formed dom

Comment: @G Siry i use id='join' for img

Comment: @G Siry $('#'+id_value).attr('src', newSrc); it doesnt change the icon. :(

Comment: see my edited answer .. you should not have multiple elements in your table with the same id. I have corrected your code see my answer. Use a class name instead ..

Comment: @G Siry its working now, can you pls explain this to me $('#'+id_value + ' .join') instead of just ('#id'). thanks alot